# Unexpected behavior of KeyTake

Tags: bugs, associations

```
list = {{a, b, c, e}, {1, 2, b, h}, {"a", "h", 3, 5}};
asso = GroupBy[list, {#[[1]], #[[2]]} &]
```

> ```
> <|{a, b} -> {{a, b, c, e}}, 
>   {1, 2} -> {{1, 2, b, h}}, 
>   {"a","h"} -> {{"a", "h", 3, 5}}|>
> ```

There is a problem in this code, since `"a"` and `"h"` might be two keys.  However, `KeyExistsQ` is not `Listable`, but `KeyTake` is.

```
KeyExistsQ[asso, {"a", "h"}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
KeyTake[asso, {"a", "h"}]
```

> ```
> <||>
> ```

So I wrap `Key` around `{"a", "h"}` to eliminate ambiguity.

```
KeyTake[asso, Key[{"a", "h"}]]
```

> ```
> <||>
> ```

Contrast the above with

```
KeyDrop[asso, Key[{"a", "h"}]]
```

> ```
> <|{a, b} -> {{a, b, c, e}}, {1, 2} -> {{1, 2, b, h}}|>
> ```

Have I found a bug? Tested on V10.4

Comment: `KeyTake[asso, {{"a", "h"}}]`...

Comment: I would have expected `Key` to work. I think you should report it to WRI.

Comment: @ciao glad to see that, where do you see such examples in Help Page？ or You just tried it out?

Comment: @HyperGroups - it *is* how it's documented, not sure what you're asking: `{x,y,...}` is an argument with multiple keys, `{{x,y,...}}` is an argument with a single, compound key.

Comment: I think there is a real issue here and the question should not be closed.

Comment: You have found a bug in `KeyDrop`. See update to my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

The behavioral discrepancy can be shown with a very simple example.

```
assoc = <|1 -> 1, 2 -> 2|>;
{KeyTake[assoc, 1], KeyTake[assoc, Key[1]], KeyTake[assoc, Key[1][assoc]]}
```

> `{<|1 -> 1|>, <||>, <|1 -> 1|>}`

```
{KeyDrop[assoc, 1], KeyDrop[assoc, Key[1]], KeyDrop[assoc, Key[1][assoc]]}
```

> `{<|2 -> 2|>, <|2 -> 2|>, <|2 -> 2|>}`

Surely the behavior of `KeyTake[assoc, Key[1]]` and `KeyDrop[assoc, Key[1]]` should be more consistent. Personally, I feel it is the behavior of `KeyDrop` that is wrong.

#### Update

I reported this issue to Wolfram tech support. Yesterday, 2016-Jul-7, I received a reply from which I quote the relevant section.

> It does appear that KeyDrop is not behaving consistently. I have forwarded an incident report to our developers with the information you provided. If I receive any progress on this issue, you will be posted regarding the same.

This confirms my suspicion that it is `KeyDrop` and not `KeyTake` that is behaving badly.

Comment: In version 11, the line of code with `KeyDrop` now returns `{<|2 -> 2|>, <|1 -> 1, 2 -> 2|>, <|2 -> 2|>}`

Comment: @Xavier. I don't have V11, but if that's the case, `KeyDrop` has been fixed in V11. I suggest you update the question to mention the fact.