# KeyDrop does not respect Key in V11

Tags: functions, associations, filtering

```
KeyDrop[<|a -> 1|>, Key[a]]
```

> ```
> <|a -> 1|>
> ```

```
KeyTake[<|a -> 1|>, Key[a]]
```

> ```
> <||>
> ```

closely related but not the same: [Unexpected behavior of KeyTake](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/112327/5478)

Are there any consistent rules about using `Key`?

Win 7 V11.0.0 V11.0.1

Cloud V11.0.1

Worked as expected in V10.4

---

This leads to problems like how to extract `{a,b}->3`:

```
KeyTake[<|a -> 1, b -> 2, {a, b} -> 3|>, {a, b}]
KeyTake[<|a -> 1, b -> 2, {a, b} -> 3|>, Key[{a, b}]]
```

> ```
> <|a -> 1, b -> 2|>
>
> <||>
> ```

Not to mention backward compatibility.

---

> A support case with the identification [CASE:3733760] was created.

Comment: Which version of V11?

Comment: I don't have V11.0.1, but I get the same results as you on Linux x86 64 bit

Comment: (1) The second argument of `KeyDrop` and `KeyTake` is taken literally as a single key or a list of keys. `KeyDrop[assoc, Key[a]]` will not work unless there is a `Key[a]` as an actual key. (2) You could do `KeyTake[<|a -> 1, b -> 2, {a, b} -> 3|>, {{a, b}}]`.

Comment: @ilian Sorry but I see that. The point is: it wasn't the case, your comment does not explain whether it was intended change, documentation doesn't reflect this, what is a possible motivation behind that change, was Key handling changed somewhere else, what is the big picture with respect to Key and associations.

Comment: I meant the current behavior; it is an intended change (a bug fix in V11), motivated in part by the previous question you linked. As far as I know. Perhaps someone else will write an answer to your deeper questions.

Comment: @ilian I see, I hope I will get more info from Support. I'm surprised that this way was choosen to achieve consistency in linked topic. The more that `Lookup` and `Part` are honoring `Key`s.  Nevertheless such change should be emphasized in documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR**

The wrapper `Key` is interpreted verbatim by all `?Key*` and `Association`-related functions, the current exception being `Lookup` which strips one level of `Key`.

Other symbols prior to the introduction of associations, that act on expressions of any head and have a position-related argument, ask for the wrapper `Key` in order to be used in a special way on associations, except for keys specified as strings.

---

**About consistency**

> Are there any consistent rules about using `Key`?

*Proposition.* When the syntax of a function explicitly asks for a key as an argument, wrapping this key `key` in the symbol `Key` defines a different key, the expression of which is `Key[key]`.

Leaving aside the symbols `KeyDrop` and `Lookup` which I address further down, this rule seems to apply on all `?Key*` symbols and other `Association`-related functions, in the mentioned versions 10.4.1, 11.0.0 and 11.0.1.

As examples about this rule and its constancy, consider `KeyExistsQ` and `KeyMemberQ`. We have in all three versions:

```
KeyExistsQ[<|a -> 1|>, a]
(* True *)

KeyExistsQ[<|a -> 1|>, Key[a]]
(* False *)

KeyMemberQ[<|a -> 1|>, a]
(* True *)

KeyMemberQ[<|a -> 1|>, Key[a]]
(* False *)
```

which shows that the keys `key` and `Key[key]` are different. Note that the last input used to give `True` in 10.2 and earlier, so the change made in 10.3 seems to support the proposed rule.

**About the change of behavior in `KeyDrop`**

> What is a possible motivation behind that change? *[from OP's [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128171/keydrop-does-not-respect-key-in-v11#comment346764_128171)]*

In versions 10.4.1 and earlier, `KeyDrop` fails to make the distinction between the arguments `key` and `Key[key]`. One level of `Key` was stripped:

```
$Version
(* "10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)" *)

KeyDrop[<|a -> 1|>, a]
(* <||> *)

KeyDrop[<|a -> 1|>, Key[a]]
(* <||> *)

KeyDrop[<|Key[a] -> 1|>, Key[a]]
(* <|Key[a] -> 1|> *)

KeyDrop[<|Key[a] -> 1|>, Key[Key[a]]]
(* <||> *)
```

This wrong behavior is fixed as of 11.0.1 and solves the inconsistency with all other `?Key*` symbols.

**Special cases**

*About `Lookup`*

`Lookup` explicitly asks for a key,

> `Lookup[assoc, key]` looks up the value associated with `key` in the association `assoc`

so it should satisfied the proposed rule, but this is not the case:

```
Lookup[<|a -> 1, b -> 2|>, a]
(* 1 *)

Lookup[<|a -> 1, b -> 2|>, Key[a]]
(* 1 *)
```

`Lookup` could be seen as an exception to the rule, and its particular behavior is documented in the sections "Properties & Relations" and "Possible Issues".

*About other symbols*

There are symbols that need the keys to be wrapped into `Key` in order to be correctly interpreted. These symbols all have definitions prior to the introduction of associations, which probably explain why a particular syntax is needed to get an unambiguous additional definition.

For instance, prior to 10.0, `Part` accepts only integers or valid `Span` specifications. Using the wrapper `Key` allow to distinguish between the position in the association and the corresponding key, stripping one level of `Key` in the process:

```
assoc = <|a -> x, 1 -> y, Key[1] -> z|>;

assoc[[1]]
(* x *)

assoc[[Key[1]]]
(* y *)

assoc[[Key[Key[1]]]]
(* z *)
```

Similarly, we have for other symbols with a position-related argument:

```
Extract[assoc, 1]
(* x *)

Extract[assoc, Key[1]]
(* y *)

ReplacePart[assoc, 1 -> 0]
(* <|a -> 0, 1 -> y, Key[1] -> z|> *)

ReplacePart[assoc, Key[1] -> 0]
(* <|a -> x, 1 -> 0, Key[1] -> z|> *)

MapAt[f, assoc, 1]
(* <|a -> f[x], 1 -> y, Key[1] -> z|> *)

MapAt[f, assoc, Key[1]]
(* <|a -> x, 1 -> f[y], Key[1] -> z|> *)
```

For all these symbols, as mentioned by Kuba in a comment below, a key specified as a string need not to be wrapped in `Key`. This shortcut is unambiguously defined, and therefore distinguishable from other available syntaxes. Taking the example of `Part`:

```
<|"a" -> 1|>[[Key["a"]]]
(* 1 *)

<| "a" -> 1 |>[["a"]]
(* 1 *)
```

Comment: +1 that was my concussion too at the end but I didn't want to talk to myself ;) Please consider moving summary to the top so that the point is clear. Would you call my initial confusion natural or was your impression that I should've read docs more carefully? :)

Comment: I'm not sure the documentation helps to find out a general rule here. The docs for `KeyTake`, `KeyDrop`, `KeyExistsQ`, `KeyMemberQ`, ... do not mention the symbol `Key`, and the ref page of the latter is not really exhaustive. All this, plus the recent changes in `KeyDrop` and `KeyMemberQ` (perhaps others), do not help. I had the same initial confusion (and "concussion" :p).

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I make many typos and some of them escapte the review :) p.s. worth to mention special handling of string keys by "old" functions: `<|"a" -> 1|>[["a"]]`

Comment: Re concussion - I thought it was a nice typo as we were talking about confusion :-) Re string keys. Good point, I am going to update the answer.