# KeyTake, KeyDrop fail with Transpose in Dataset

Tags: dataset, associations

I think similar to [unexpected-behavior-of-keytake](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112327/unexpected-behavior-of-keytake) there are other issues with 
v11.0 `KeyTake` and (more useful) `KeyDrop` that show up in `Dataset` only:

In `Associations` `Transpose` can precede manual listing of keys:

```
ds = <|"a" -> <|"x" -> 1, "y" -> 2|>, "b" -> <|"x" -> 3, "y" -> 4|>, 
  "c" ->  <|"x" -> 5, "y" -> 6|> |>
```

That is:

```
ds // Transpose // Query[{"x"}]
```

> <|"x" -> <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 3, "c" -> 5|>|>

And `KeyTake`

```
ds // Transpose // KeyTake["x"]
```

But in Dataset, this works:

```
Dataset[ds][Transpose, {"x"}]
```

Yet this fails (similarly for `KeyDrop`)

```
Dataset[ds][Transpose, KeyTake["x"]]
```

> Message:  The first two levels of Association[(*String->*)..] cannot
>   be transposed.

Known bug?

Comment: In `Dataset`,you need `Dataset[ds][Transpose /* "x"]` or `Dataset[ds][Transpose /* KeyTake["x"]]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This operation used to work back in v10.0 when the dataset type-checking was less aggressive, but has been broken since v10.1.  The root cause is that the type inferencer cannot deduce the result type of the `KeyTake` operation and thus errs on the side of caution to reject the final transposition.

**Work-arounds**

1) Query outside of `Dataset` (the #1 strategy when faced with dataset weirdness):

```
ds // Query[Transpose, KeyTake["x"]] // Dataset
```

2) Use `KeySelect` instead of `KeyTake`:

```
Dataset[ds][Transpose, KeySelect[# === "x" &]]
```

3) Hack like there's no tomorrow:

```
Needs["TypeSystem`"]

Block[{FailureType = AnyType&}
, Dataset[ds][Transpose, KeyTake["x"]]
]
```

**Discussion**

*This analysis is current as of version 11.0.1.*

The operation works just fine in a stand-alone query:

```
ds // Query[Transpose, KeyTake["x"]]
(* <|"x" -> <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 3, "c" -> 5|>|> *)
```

but, as noted in the question, fails as a dataset query:

```
Dataset[ds][Transpose, KeyTake["x"]]
(* ... failure ... *)
```

This gives us a clue that it is probably a type-inferencing error.  Using `traceTypes` from [(89081)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89081/142) confirms that guess:

```
traceTypes[Dataset[ds2]][Transpose, KeyTake["x"]]
```

[image: traceTypes output]

Specifically, the type inferencer does not know what type results when `KeyTake` is applied to our association type:

```
Needs["TypeSystem`"]

TypeApply[KeyTake["x"], {DeduceType[<|"x" -> 1, "y" -> 2|>]}]
(* UnknownType *)
```

As a consequence, the inferencer cannot deduce whether the `AssociationTranspose` will succeed.  It errs on the side of caution and rejects the operation.

Note that `KeyTake` in itself operates properly:

```
Dataset[ds][All, KeyTake["x"]]
```

[image: Standalone KeyTake]

But the lack of type information for the result will block the operation of subsequent operators for which the inferencer takes a defensive stance.  `Transpose` is one such operator as we can see from its recognized type signatures:

```
Signatures[Transpose // Query // Normal]
```

[image: Transpose Signatures]

The second-last type signature rule kicks in when an unrecognized input type is encountered and is responsible for error message that we see.

We can check what type signatures are supported for `KeyTake`:

```
Signatures[KeyTake]
(* ... blank ... *)
```

Aha... there are none.  Contrast this with, for example, `KeySelect`:

```
Signatures[KeySelect]
```

[image: KeySelect signatures]

The presence of the signature implies that `KeySelect` will work -- which it does:

```
Dataset[ds][Transpose, KeySelect[# == "x" &]]
```

[image: KeySelect result]

`KeyDrop` has no valid signatures either:

```
Signatures[KeyDrop]
(* ... blank ... *)
```

Our conclusion is that `KeyTake` and `KeyDrop` are not fully supported in dataset queries.  This omission could be considered as either an incomplete implementation or as a bug (reader's choice).

Normally, setting `FailureAction -> None` will inhibit any aggressive error-checking in query operations.  Unfortunately the type inferencer rarely (if ever?) respects this setting.  And indeed it does not help us with the cases under discussion.  Incomplete implementation and/or bug?

Comment: Thanks WReach, another detailed analysis. I think the type-system is a regression to C++/templates, is not that useful for its main intended application: formatting - in fact more often than not I Normalize it away and run ad-hoc formatting.

Comment: Indeed.  I tend to treat `Dataset` as a display wrapper much like `MatrixForm`, only adding it at the very end when it is time to visualize.  I find the type deducer used for dataset creation to be much more reliable than the type inferencer used for dataset querying.   On the other hand `Query` seems to be much more solid than it was in the early 10.x releases and I find myself using it quite a lot on general expressions (often displacing `Map`, `Part`, etc even for simple transformations).

Comment: is the type system and inference engine invoked in `Query` even when querying Associations (rather than Datasets)?

Comment: Type-inferencing is not invoked for `... // Query[...]` where the left-hand side is a non-dataset expression.  We can observe this by establishing ``On[TypeSystem`TypeApply]`` before evaluating `<|"a"->1|> // Query["a"]` and `Dataset[<|"a"->1|>]["a"]`.  Only in the latter case will we see invocation of the type-inferencing system (`TypeApply`).  And, of course, both you and I need only count bruises from attempts to use `Dataset[...][...]`.  :)  It has been my experience that non-dataset queries are reliable (and as far as I can recall every rare exception has been fixed).

Comment: That's good news, gives hope for a ground-up re-implementation of Dataset's formatting based on the built-in expression manipulation (which in addition might allow pattern matching). For example, in v10 formatting workarounds using Framed, Column, Grid etc, within and outside Dataset allowed a lot of freedom, so it's feasible. Unfortunately v11 broke a lot of these.